# Image resize using PHP5 and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, image, resize

Hi I want to resize image when in display on details section. For that I checked many PHP scripts but its not working in my locale. Some scripts showing image path must start with / but when I give like that its shows image is not found. Also most of the scripts demo page shows fake images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is crop image while image upload. Please find below code for image crop using GD library may it help you.

```
<?php
function createThumb($upfile, $dstfile, $max_width, $max_height){
   $size = getimagesize($upfile);
   $width = $size[0];
   $height = $size[1];
   $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
   $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;
   if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height)) {
           $tn_width = $width;
           $tn_height = $height;

   } elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height) {
           $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
           $tn_width = $max_width;

   } else {
           $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
           $tn_height = $max_height;

   }
   if($size['mime'] == "image/jpeg"){

           $src = ImageCreateFromJpeg($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           imageinterlace( $dst, true);
           ImageJpeg($dst, $dstfile, 100);
   } else if ($size['mime'] == "image/png"){
           $src = ImageCreateFrompng($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           Imagepng($dst, $dstfile);

   } else {

           $src = ImageCreateFromGif($upfile);
           $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width, $tn_height);
           imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width, $tn_height,$width, $height);
           imagegif($dst, $dstfile);
   }
}

//usage

if(isset($_FILES['upload_Image']['name']) && $_FILES['upload_Image']['name']!=='') {
    $ext = substr($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'], strpos($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'],'.'), strlen($_FILES['upload_Image']['name'])-1); 

    $imgNormal = time().$ext;
    $normalDestination = "Photos/Orignal/" . $imgNormal;
    $httpRootLarge = "Photos/Large/" . $imgNormal;
    $httpRootSmall = "Photos/Small/" . $imgNormal;
    $httpRootThumb = "Photos/Thumb/" . $imgNormal;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_Image']['tmp_name'], $normalDestination);
    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootLarge,680,604); #For 604x604 Image 
    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootSmall,500,300); #For 500x300 Image
    createThumb($normalDestination,$httpRootThumb,130,100); #For 130x100 Image
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Create thumbnail for the image (through graphic library in PHP) and store it (better for performance).
2. Resize the image dynamically with PHP graphics library and show it.

You may also refer this page for more details: http://php.net/manual/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ImageMagick. You can find lot of examples in Google, I have only Perl example.

Answer (score 0):

The guys form nettuts have a great tut on this topic: [Image Resizing Made Easy with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) 
:)